# Transforming data between 2 structures

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to calculate a score based on departments in groups. To simplify that I used only 1 group as an example.

I'm receiving this data structure:

```
const data = [{
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 80,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Engineering",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 40,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Executive",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 40,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "OOO Boost",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 60,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Engineering",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 100,
            "count": 2,
            "department": "Supporting Department",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 20,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Designers",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 20,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Executive",
            "group": "Group one"
        }
    ];
```

and I need to create a data structure for a heatmap:

```
const heatmapData = [
{
  row: 'Group one',
  columns: [
    { 
      name: 'Engineering', 
      averageScore: 70,  // (80[score] * 1[count] + 60[score] * 1[count]) / 2[sum of count -> 1+1]
    },
    { 
      name: 'Supporting Department', 
      averageScore: 100,  // 100[score] * 2[count] / 2[sum of count -> 2]
    },
    .... next unique departments
  ]
}
]
```

I'm a bit stacked with some simple solution of grouping data with calculation. Could you help me please? Thank you

Comment: so you basically want to collect all the scores and sum them together. is this correct?

Comment: also if that's how you want `columns` you do realise that would be an array?

Comment: @TheBombSquad why should it necessary be an array? you can make is also an object

Comment: @MrJami the way they had it, specifically that would be an array though

Comment: true, the format how Jack used it seems more to be like an array. @TheBombSquad gotcha

Comment: Sorry @TheBombSquad columns should be an array - corrected. And yes, I want to collect all scores through all the departments.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to _at least_ present your own attempt here, even if that was not successful. This site is not a code-writing service.

Comment: btw, @Jack for the `"Supporting Department"` department, the average score is `50` right?

Comment: @TheBombSquad No, actually it is 100. I added one more object with calculation.

Comment: so the number that count has is completely irrelevant then?

Comment: @TheBombSquad you can see how it works from the formula above. At first, you need to multiply each score by count, then take the sum of the results and divide it by the sum of all counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your data based on the `group` and for each `group`, group it on `department` and sum up `score` and `count`. Once you have this object, you can calculate average for each `department`.

```js
const data = [{ "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 80, "count": 1, "department": "Engineering", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 40, "count": 1, "department": "Executive", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 40, "count": 1, "department": "OOO Boost", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 60, "count": 1, "department": "Engineering", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 100, "count": 2, "department": "Supporting Department", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 20, "count": 1, "department": "Designers", "group": "Group one" }, { "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9", "score": 20, "count": 1, "department": "Executive", "group": "Group one" } ],
  grouped = data.reduce((r, {group, department, score, count}) => {
    r[group] = r[group] || {};
    r[group][department] = r[group][department] || {department, totalScore: 0, count: 0 };
    r[group][department].totalScore += score * count;
    r[group][department].count += count;
    return r;
  },{}),
  result = Object.keys(grouped).map(k => {
    const columns = Object.values(grouped[k]).map(d => ({
      department: d.department,
      averageScore: d.totalScore/d.count
    }));
    return {row: k, columns };
  })
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group items into the dictionary:

```
let group = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if(!acc[val.group]) acc[val.group] = {};
  if(!acc[val.group][val.department]) acc[val.group][val.department] = {sum:0, count: 0, averageScore: 0};
  acc[val.group][val.department] = {
    sum: acc[val.group][val.department].sum+val.score,
    count: acc[val.group][val.department].count + 1,
    averageScore: (acc[val.group][val.department].sum+val.score) / (acc[val.group][val.department].count + 1)
  }
return acc
}, {});
```

then map it to requested format:

```
Object.keys(group).map(row => {
  return {
    row: row,
    columns: Object.keys(group[row]).map(col => {return {name: col, averageScore: group[row][col].averageScore}})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to explain how it works.. so we know that objects are pointers more than they are values.. I used that principle throughout the solution. I have the array to return(where I push stuff), then I had 2 Objects to store values(and editing those Objects edited the "values" in the array), so in the array you pass in, I basically add values to these objects and link them in the array(the format you desire)

**UPDATED AGAIN**.. I applied the logic of your calculation examples >:D

```js
function group(array){
  let arr=[]; let groups={}; let departments={}
  array.forEach(a=>{
    if(!groups[a.group]){ //setting each group
      groups[a.group]={row:a.group,columns:[]}
      arr.push(groups[a.group])
    }
    if(!departments[a.department]){ //setting each department
      departments[a.department]=[{name:a.department,averageScore:a.score*a.count},a.count] //score * count and count(because of your calculation examples)
      groups[a.group].columns.push(departments[a.department][0])
    }
    else{ //adding department when they already exist
      departments[a.department][1]+=a.count //count
      departments[a.department][0].averageScore+=a.score*a.count //score * count
      //(because of your calculation examples)
    }
  })
  Object.keys(departments).forEach(a=>departments[a][0].averageScore/=departments[a][1])
  return arr
}

console.log(group(data))
```

```html
<script>
//to not take out unnecesary space in the answer
window.data = [{
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 80,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Engineering",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 40,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Executive",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 40,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "OOO Boost",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 60,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Engineering",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 100,
            "count": 2,
            "department": "Supporting Department",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 20,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Designers",
            "group": "Group one"
        },
        {
            "id": "cklt7ln1k0922o0sabjkk74m9",
            "score": 20,
            "count": 1,
            "department": "Executive",
            "group": "Group one"
        }
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: If `Supporting Department` appears just one time in array, `averageScore` should be `100/1 = 100` right?

Comment: the count in `Supporting Department` was 2 though